# Sendgrid SMTP via Rails email metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, sendgrid, sendgrid-rails

When using ActionMailer mailers and having the SMTP settings as Sendgrid, is it possible to get a reference to the Sendgrid email when the mailer runs, or would it require migrating to the Sendgrid REST api?

Answer (score 0):

With ActionMailer, it isn't possible but with the gem yes:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby